# Hide Text inside of brackets via CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, hide

i have to hide some text inside of brackets. For example:

- Argentinien (Rotweine)
- Mendoza (Rotweine)

I want to get rid of "(Rotweine)". Unfortunately i have no chance to make  or something else arount the brackets. So i have to do it via css. My idea is to do this via the property "content: (...);" - but I'm kind of stuck there. :/

Anybody an idea of how to solve this issue?

Comment: Providing HTML instead of plain text will be more helpful

Comment: This is not possible with CSS. CSS cannot select text nodes or **specific** text. You need Javascript.

Comment: @Paulie_D: Ok. Thank you. And how can this be done with the help of JS?

Comment: Possible Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864605/how-to-change-style-of-a-arbitrary-part-of-html-text

Answer (score -1):

make a class for brackets and use this:

```
color:transparent
```

or

```
display:none
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you only want to do this visually, adding a pseudo element with the content and hiding the label itself this would be an option.

HTML

```
<div class="wein">
  Argentinien (Rotweine)
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wein {
  color: transparent;
}
.wein:before {
  display: block;
  content: 'Argentinien';
  color: black;
}
```

https://codepen.io/ithimo/pen/WNeqaPL

**This is by no means a nice, intuitive or can be done automatically without the help of javascript.**

Comment: Thank you for this. Unfortunately i hove dozens of "(Rotwein)" points with very individual names and basically no individual classes around. So i have to write for each name a seperate line of code. Think of it like a list of countries - each with "(Rotwein)" bracket-thing.  :/

Isn't there another way? maybe with the help of JS?